# What's it called when you use the characteristics of a noun as an adjective?

Tags: terminology

Please feel free to edit this question so it makes sense.

For example, if you're saying:

> He has a bearish personality.

We're using the qualities of a bear, (big, grizzly, perhaps dangerous), to describe his personality.

> The party was very British.

Conjures images of cups of tea, and polite reserved conversation; it's not saying the party was literally made of up British people.

These aren't similes or metaphors. Is there a term for it?

Answer (score 2):

They are derived adjectives.  For example:

- sheep - a noun
- sheepish - a derived adjective
- sheepishly - a derived adverb
- sheepishness - a derived noun

Answer (score 0):

> **[Bahuvrihi](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bahuvrihi)**   A compound word functioning as an adjective whose last element is in
>   origin a noun. For example, in the phrase high-fiber diet, the
>   compound high-fiber is a bahuvrihi modifying diet that ends in the
>   noun fiber.